# media queries in responsive design

Tags: responsive-design

I'm creating a responsive website. For the CSS for smaller monitors I wrote this:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 1224px) and (max-width: 1440px) {
/*css here*/
}
```

and the HTML part for the css:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen (min-width: 1224px)" href="css/monitor.css" />
```

and when I create the css for smartphones:
html:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="(min-width: 320px)" href="css/mobile.css" />
```

css:

```
@media handheld and (min-device-width: 320px),
handheld and (max-device-width: 767px) {
/*css here*/
}
```

1. dont' see my css setting on smartphones
2. in the monitor I see what I wrote the mobile.css

What shall I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the media type 'screen' rather then 'handheld'. Most mobile devices will say they are a screen . So your css would be:

```
@media screen and (min-device-width: 320px),
screen and (max-device-width: 767px) {
/*css here*/
}
```

Comment: Yes, why is that? Also, why do some smartphones identify themselves as PDA's when they're not?

Comment: The Handheld media type has become redundant as Apple & Android declare themselves as screens, I believe that the handheld media type was for older devices which had a very basic web browser.